# Unit testing object instantiation static call to a third party library

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Is there a way to control the static call to getInstance method of a third party library using mockito.
For ex :

```
public static ThirdPartyLibraryFactory createInstance() {
     
        return ThirdPartyLibrary.getInstance(
                param1, param2
        );
}
```

Considering i cannot use powermockito or anything that helps testing static calls
Also, consider those param1 to be some credentials and thirdpartylibrary will return a successful object if credentials are authentic. otherwise it will throw an error. And there is no way i can get the real credentials while testing due to complexity of the code. I would like to somehow intercept that call and return my dummy object.

Comment: Can you wrap this call with your code that won't use static and will delegate the call to this code, so that you could mock your code with regular mockito techniques?

Comment: Hmm, thats what my friend also told me. Thank You!!